# Get date from database

Tags: php

I am new here and this is my first problem,

I try to get date stored in database.

I use `echo` why does not work.

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", "<?php echo $D->birthday ?>");
echo $date->format("Y");
```

Please correct me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is wrong syntax near `$D->birthday`.

Try

```
$date = DateTime::createFromFormat("Y-m-d", $D->birthday);
echo $date->format("Y");
```

Comment: I wasn't expecting that, what a shame.